# OpenSTF shows Connected Android Device but gets Disconnected after preparing and connected iOS device is not showing

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, adb

I have started the stf using "stf local". It shows that the device connected but after "Preparing" it goes to "Disconnected" status.

My system config is
MacOS - 10.15.7
node version - v8.17.0
rethinkdb version - 2.4.0

"adb devices" shows the connected device.

when I run "stf doctor", it gives output like below:-
OS Arch: x64
OS Platform: darwin
OS Platform: 19.6.0
Using Node 8.17.0
Using ZeroMQ 4.3.3
Using RethinkDB 2.4.0
Using ADB 1.0.41
Using GraphicsMagick 1.3.35
Using ProtoBuf 3.13.0

Answer (score 0):

You must run stf_ios_support "coordinator" in order to provide IOS devices to an STF server. See https://github.com/devicefarmer/stf_ios_support